# Can this code result in a deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am not very good at multithreading and am baffled by this code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        new Thread(Main::test).start();
    }

    private static synchronized void test() {
        new Thread(Main::test).start();
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }
}
```

Can it result in a deadlock or not? If so, then why have I not been able to get it to deadlock? My thinking is, thread 1 acquires lock on `test()`, then another thread, created in `test()` tries to acquire it and they should be waiting on each other. But they aren't, why not?

I know, that adding `join()` in `test()` will make it result in a deadlock, but how come the example below doesn't use joins and deadlocks?

This code results in a deadlock literally every time I run it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Thread(Main::test).start();
        new Thread(Main::test2).start();
    }

    private static void test() {
        synchronized (Integer.class) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            synchronized (Float.class) {
                System.out.println("Acquired float");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void test2() {
        synchronized (Float.class) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            synchronized (Integer.class) {
                System.out.println("Acquired integer");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that `start` would wait for something?

Comment: @Henry I think you meant "make something wait"?

Comment: @Wow `start` doesn't wait for anything, and will not make anything wait. It simply starts a thread. It is that thread that *might* wait on the `synchronized` method.

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote. The thread executing the `start` is not blocked by anything and just finishes.

Comment: I don't think a SO question thread is a good format for what you need, which is to go through either Josh Bloch's book "Effective Java", or Brian Goetz's book "Java Concurrency in Practise".

Comment: @MikaelGueck I am getting there. I have read a couple of first chapters from Brian Goetz's book, but since I don't use raw threads in my day to day job I don't know how certain things work.

Comment: @Henry okay, I thought you were talking about `start` inside `test`, but you meant `start` inside `main`. As I said, I thought the `start` inside `main` calls `test`, `test` creates a new thread, which waits for the thread created in `main` to finish executing, and while it waits, the thread from `main` also waits, hence deadlock. <- This is what I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the code in the first example cannot deadlock. The newly started threads will simply wait until the previous thread exits the method to acquire the lock.

The code in the second example deadlocks because the locks are acquired in opposite order and because of the sleeps are reliably going to block each other.

Comment: However, even the second example isn't *guaranteed* to deadlock, since the JVM is allowed to coarsen the locks. It just happens to, in a certain environment.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how sleeps block each other? What does this have to do with sleeps? I added them thinking that I have to give both threads enough time to start.

Comment: Not guaranteed no. Just highly likely.

Comment: @Wow, in the second example you are acquiring locks in order A,B on one thread and B,A on another thread. The first thread acquires the lock on A and then sleeps, while the second thread acquires the lock on B and then sleeps. Both threads wake up, and then (without releasing their locks) attempt to acquire the lock held by the other. Without the sleeps, there is a higher chance of one thread acquiring and then releasing locks A,B (or B,A) before the other thread even runs. If that happens, they wouldn't deadlock.

Comment: Re, "Can you explain how sleeps block each other?" The sleeps do not cause the deadlock, but whether or not the deadlock happens is a matter of _timing_. The sleep calls merely change the timing to create a wide window in which it is possible for the deadlock to happen. So wide, in this case, that the deadlock is virtually certain. In "real" code that is susceptible to deadlock, the windows of opportunity can be very narrow (e.g., a few microseconds every few minutes.) A program can run for weeks or months without deadlock, then suddenly... Bang! (Don't ask me how I know!)

Comment: @ChrisShain I think I understood how to think about this. In the first example Main.class is _in use_ by thread1, but not yet _in use_ by thread2, so thread2 just waits and then starts executing. However, in the second example both Integer.class and Float.class locks are _in use_ so the 2 threads can't acquire them. Is this a correct way of thinking?

Comment: @ChrisShain can you please explain why in this example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html deadlock works without Thread.sleep? Does a method call to bowBack take such a long time that both threads have enough time to start?

Comment: It is the same as your second example above. As stated, the thread sleep isn't necessary. Just makes a deadlock more likely.

Answer (score -1):

When you're at the phase where you're first learning how to think about concurrency and related problems, I would very much recommend using physical props to keep your thoughts and hypotheses clear and explicit.

For example, grab a A3 sheet of paper, set up a "race track" where you use something like Monopoly pieces to signify what you're doing in your code, what you expect to happen, and what your experiments show actually happens.

When your experiments don't work out, take a small piece of the beginning first, and verify it. Then add some more, and so on.

It helps if you read about how actual computers (not the CS ideal or conceptual computers) currently work. How the CPU gets data out of the main memory into its cache. How two or three CPUs decide which one of them can handle data in one cache line at a time. Then, how the Java Memory Model needs you to write your source code so that the JVM knows what you actually mean to happen.